# Make a git repository read-only over ssh depending on the key used

Tags: shell, git

I want a git repository, accessible over ssh, to be read-only when used with certain keys. With other keys access to the full system is okay.

Here is my solution.

git-readonlyshell:

```
if echo "$2" | egrep -q ^git-upload-pack; then
  sh -c "$2"
else
  echo Error: read only access 1>&2
fi
```

.ssh/authorized_keys:

```
command="./git-readonlyshell -c \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"" ...
```

Thoughts?

Any scenario in which this would break?

Comment: Why not just have a user that is read-only for the repository and use one user for full-access, and the other for read-only?

Comment: @rolfl I could. But then I have to specify a longer path after the `:`, meaning `user@server:/full/path/to/repo`

Comment: @nafg: Can you please roll back your last edit if it was in response to GoodPerson's answer? The answer becomes somewhat pointless when you edit your question like this.

Comment: @ChrisWue: I rolled back the edit, so that the answer makes sense again. nafg: If you want to ask a follow-up question, you should *append* it to the original question instead of changing your question.

Comment: @ChrisWue: trying to recall, are you talking about the fact that I added "Any scenario in which this would break?" If so no, it was no in response to GoodPerson's answer, it was my original intention and I realized I had been unclear.

Comment: @GarethRees: maybe I'm forgetting something, if you're talking about the fact that I added "Any scenario in which this would break?" then how was that not "appending"?

Comment: Wait, are you guys talking about the switch from && to if/else with an error message? If so I don't see why that bothers you. My original script was with if/else. I had posted the && on IRC for brevity, and I mistakenly had copy-pasted that version to Code Review rather than my actual code.

Comment: I just realized you're probably talking about printf vs. echo, okay  I see your point... Any objection if I un-rollback except for that?

Comment: @nafg: Sure, just keep the code as you posted it originally so the answer still makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you can find inspiration in gitolite

Comment: @Asenar: heh, actually I use gitolite on another server. For better or worse I chose not to use it in this case (a discussion of why would be more applicable to a SO question than code review though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

```
printf "%s\n" "$2" | grep -E "^git-upload-pack" && sh -c "$2"
```

Notes:

- `sh` not `bash` for portability
- The `printf` instead of `echo` is for safety.  What happens if someone puts  `"-n foo"` as `"$2"`?

Comment: It is insecure. The `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` can contain multiple command-lines, e.g., `git-upload-pack dummy; cat /etc/passwd`.